# Letting Django and Backbone.js talk in YAML?

Tags: django, json, backbone.js, yaml

So I realized it's time to jump onto the JS MVC bandwagon, and I decided to use a little bit of Backbone.js here and there to spice up my next Django project. On the server side, I am running [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/), which I also have no prior experience with.

For some reason, however, I don't really like JSON, while at the same time I hold YAML in high regard due to its legibility. Is it viable to use YAML as the data serialization format instead of JSON, what are the pros and cons, and how do I make Backbone read YAML?

Comment: Have you researched how Backbone communicates with the server?

Comment: @muistooshort My guess is extending `Backbone.sync` would suffice, then?

Comment: How do you expect to serialize models and collections to YAML? And how about parsing YAML that comes from the server?

Comment: Well, the server-side framework has a [YAML renderer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html#yamlrenderer). However, the client side situation is not so peachy - even if minified with Packer, the [JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) clocks in at >100K. Pretty hefty.

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js) minifies to 20K though. Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to using YAML over JSON here.  You will be using JSON to exchange data between server and client, not as a human-readable representation.  Sure, YAML can be nice to look at compared to JSON, but who will be looking besides the developer?  Your client is in JavaScript, it seems logical enough to use *JavaScript* Object Notation, which both client and server already understand.  Sure, it's possible to use YAML libraries on both sides to post-/pre-process the data, but it just adds an extra layer of complexity.